# Poweshell Disk space report into a HTML format to makie more cleaner?

Tags: html, azure, powershell, report, reporting

Hi I have the following powershell script which pull disk space data from azure (for a selected list of serves) and put it out in a CSV - however its never clean even with teh delimiter "," in place

Instead i would like to have it in a HTML format (More cleaner)
Any help would be good..

```
`Import-Module ActiveDirectory

# Delete reports older than 60 days
$OldReports = (Get-Date).AddDays(-60)

# Location for disk reports`your text`
Get-ChildItem "C:\Temp\DiskSpaceReport\*.*" |
Where-Object { $_.LastWriteTime -le $OldReports } |
Remove-Item -Recurse -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

# Create variable for log date
$LogDate = get-date -f yyyyMMdd

############
# Import CSV file
$Servers = Import-Csv C:\Temp\ADComputers.csv

# Loop through each system
$DiskReport = ForEach ($Server in $Servers) {

# Get system
$System = Get-ADComputer $Server.Hostname | Where-Object { $_.Enabled -eq $true } | 
Select-Object Name, DNSHostName | Sort-Object Name
Get-WmiObject win32_logicaldisk `
    -ComputerName $System.DNSHostName -Filter "Drivetype=3" `
    -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
}

# Create disk report
$DiskReport | Select-Object `
@{Label = "HostName"; Expression = { $_.SystemName } },
@{Label = "DriveLetter"; Expression = { $_.DeviceID } },
#@{Label = "DriveName"; Expression = { $_.VolumeName } },
#@{Label = "Total Capacity (GB)"; Expression = { "{0:N1}" -f ( $_.Size / 1gb) } },
#@{Label = "Free Space (GB)"; Expression = { "{0:N1}" -f ( $_.Freespace / 1gb ) } },
@{Label = 'Free Space (%)'; Expression = { "{0:P0}" -f ($_.Freespace /$_.Size) } } |

# Export report to CSV file
Export-csv -Path "C:\Temp\DiskSpaceReport\DiskReport_$logDate.txt" -NoTypeInformation -Delimiter    
","

##### EMail the report  

#Define Variables#

$fromaddress = “Myemail@email.com”
$toaddress = “sendersemail@email.com”
#$ccaddress = "notneeded@mail.com"
$Subject = “UK Disk report”
#$body = get-content “C:\users\desktop\content.html”
$attachment = “C:\temp\DiskSpaceReport\DiskReport_$logDate.txt"
$smtpserver = “relay.mail.com”

###

$message = new-object System.Net.Mail.MailMessage
$message.From = $fromaddress
$message.To.Add($toaddress)
#$message.CC.Add($ccaddress)
$message.IsBodyHtml = $True
$message.Subject = $Subject
#$attach = new-object Net.Mail.Attachment($attachment)
$message.Attachments.Add($file)
#$message.body = $body
$smtp = new-object Net.Mail.SmtpClient($smtpserver)
$smtp.Send($message)

###################################################`
```

This is what i see:
[image]

Comment: Use the Data Import Wizard when loading the data into Excel. For an HTML report, use `ConvertTo-Html` instead of `Export-Csv`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> For converting your data to `HTML` format instead of `CSV`, you can
> use `ConvertTo-Html`

Convert`$DiskReport` block into an `HTML` fragment by using `| ConvertTo-Html -Fragment`in your script.

Add `.html` type instead of `.txt`

```
 $HtmlFilePath = "C:\Temp\DiskSpaceReport\DiskReport_$LogDate.html"
```

Convert `DiskReport` information to html as below.

```
 $HtmlReport = $DiskReport | Select-Object 
 @{Label = "HostName"; Expression = { $_.SystemName } }, 
@{Label = "DriveLetter"; Expression = { $_.DeviceID } }, 
#@{Label = "DriveName"; Expression = { $_.VolumeName } }, 
#@{Label = "Total Capacity (GB)"; Expression = { "{0:N1}" -f ( $_.Size / 1gb) } 
| ConvertTo-Html -Fragment
```

Save `HTML` report to file.

```
 $HtmlFilePath = "C:\Temp\DiskSpaceReport\DiskReport_$LogDate.html" $HtmlReport | Out-File -FilePath $HtmlFilePath
 $HtmlReport | Out-File -FilePath $HtmlFilePath
```

I have used below `PowerShell` script to retrieves information about `Azure VMs`  and exports the details to `HTML` File.

```
   $resourceGroupName = "Identity-Resources"
    $vmList = Get-AzVM -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName
    $vmInfoArray = @()
    foreach ($vm in $vmList) {
        $vmInfo = [PSCustomObject]@{
            Name = $vm.Name
            ResourceGroup = $vm.ResourceGroupName
            Location = $vm.Location
            OSType = $vm.StorageProfile.OsDisk.OsType
            VMSize = $vm.HardwareProfile.VmSize
        }
        $vmInfoArray += $vmInfo | ConvertTo-Html -Fragment 
    }
    $LogDate ="16-09-2023"
    $HtmlFilePath = "/home/vallepu/File_$LogDate.html"
    $vmInfoArray| Out-File -FilePath $HtmlFilePath
    Write-Host "VM information exported to $HtmlFilePath"
```

[image]

**HTML File:**

[image]